# add a command to all leaf level commands in a python click chain commands

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a chain of commands somethig like this.

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--debug/--no-debug', default=False)
def cli(debug):
    click.echo('Debug mode is %s' % ('on' if debug else 'off'))

@cli.command()  
def sync1():
    click.echo('Syncing 1')
@cli.command()  
def sync2():
    click.echo('Syncing 1')
```

```
tool.py
Usage: tool.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --debug / --no-debug
  --help                Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  sync1
  sync2
```

This is how I would run my command in a nested fashion.

```
tool.py sync1 --help

tool.py sync2 --help
```

now imagine every leaf level command (i.e sync1 and sync2 in this case) calls some API and I want to print the name of that API.

What is the best way to achieve without changing all leaf level function (i.e sync1/sync2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is with a result callback decorator.

```py
@cli.resultcallback()
def process_result(result, **kwargs):
    click.echo('Print your API name here')
```

That should allow code to be executed after the command was invoked. However, I'm not sure if the order of execution matters to you.

Hope it helps!